# Problem with using a variable in a controller from a Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, controller

My problem is as follows:

I've got a Site VF page with fields bound to a custom Lead  object.  One of these fields is a id field that's used for contact lookup.  The controller seems to work fine but all records created with it are empty, since the lookup in the controller code returns 0 rows.

This is the controller:

```
public with sharing class VF_TabletWaitingList {

    private final CustomLead__c sales;
    private Contact c;

    public VF_TabletWaitingList(ApexPages.StandardController stdcontroller) {

      this.sales= (CustomLead__c)stdController.getRecord();
    }

    public PageReference createNew()
    {
        //CustomLead__c solumal = new CustomLead__c();
        //Set the record type on CustomLead
        RecordType r = [select Id 
                        from RecordType 
                        where Name = 'Verslun' 
                        AND SobjectType = 'CustomLead__c' limit 1];
        solumal.RecordTypeId = r.Id;

        try{
            Contact c = [select id, tx_Id__c 
                         from contact 
                         where tx_Id__c =: sales.tx_Id__c limit 1];
            system.debug('Id: '+c.tx_Id__c);
            sales.Contact__c = c.Id;
        }
        catch (Exception e){
        }
        try{
            insert sales;
            system.debug('Inserted'+sales.Id);
        }
```

The debug log for the Site user shows this:

```
09:54:31.059 (59258000)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[25]|Aggregations:0|select id, tx_Id__c from contact where tx_Id__c = :tmpVar1 limit 1
09:54:31.076 (76765000)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[25]|Rows:0
```

I thought it would be enough to refer to the sales object like I do in the standard controller.  Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to check whether your field `tx_Id__c` is referenced on the visualforce page. Otherwise this field is not available and you need to query it using SOQL:

[**StandardController Class: getRecord()**](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_pages_standardcontroller.htm)

> Note that only the fields that are referenced in the associated
>   Visualforce markup are available for querying on this SObject. All
>   other fields, including fields from any related objects, must be
>   queried using a SOQL expression.

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing that, the variable is bound to the input field on the VF page.

Comment: I would try `outputField` or just query the object: `sales = [select id, tx_Id__c, ... from customLead__c where id =: sales.id];`

Answer (score 2):

FIXED:

The problem was that the class was setup With Sharing.  Changed it to Without Sharing, then it started to work correctly.

Comment: Sorry... It doesn't let me comment on your solution since I don't have enough reputation, but I had something I wanted to add. Solution: User did not have permissions and so could not see the records. Changed the class to specify 'without sharing'. Addition: So that you don't have to run the entire page in the 'without sharing' context, you could specify a method call to either an inner class or a separate class. public class with sharing MyClass { //Some stuff up here public class without sharing MyInnerClass { public static List<SObject> mySOQLCall(String someFilter) { //work } } }

Comment: Be very aware of the repercussions of using the `without sharing` keywords on a class. You're bypassing the record sharing configuration of your org and could be granting the user who is visiting this page access to _far_ more records than they would normally have access to. It would be a better solution to determine why the sharing rules are preventing access to these records than to allow the VF page controller class to ignore security altogether.

Comment: Yeah, it can be a bit problematic to troubleshoot these Site Users, since they don't show up in the normal Users list and they do not have a Role, which governs sharing in our org (and most orgs for that matter).  Now that I've given it more thought, I guess I can put a custom field on these Site Users and have the sharing rules reflect that, ie share Accounts & Contacts with users who fit the criteria.

Comment: addendum:  I'm just discovering now that these users can be added to Public Groups. Never really imagined that it was possible.  That should fix the Sharing dilemma.